# How do i replace different strings to 1 same string using PHP?

Tags: php, str-replace

For example i have a string:

```
$string = "I am a happy person";
```

How can I replace 2 or more words:

For example:

```
"am" and "person" to a same word "world",
```

So that i get the output of:

```
"I world a happy world";
```

Comment: why not use `str_replace` ?

Answer (score 1):

use [str_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), like:

```
$string = "I am a happy person";
$replace_with = array("world", "world");
$replace = array("am", "person");
echo str_replace($replace, $replace_with, $string);
```

To expand a little to answer the other comment, yes try this:

```
$string = "I am a happy person";

// you can make this array as long as you like
$replace = array("am", "person", 'three', 'four', 'five');

// this uses just the single word 'world' and it will be used to 
// replace all the words in the $replace array
echo str_replace($replace, 'world', $string);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but this is just a short string, what is i have a longer string or bunch of datas?
I want to scan the entire and replace many different words to 1 word.
Is there any other way other than using array?